# Secret documents digital safes without an overriding key?

Tags: safety, security

Are there any safes which can be opened with a programmable keypad combination or thumb fingerprint but do not come with a key?

I am concerned about the fact that if somebody steals my key they will bypass the digital circuit.

I'm looking for a mid range solution. Box strength is not an issue. Size is about half a meter cubed.

Comment: If you're really concerned about someone stealing it, lock all your keys in the safe. Problem solved. Although you've got a whole different problem when your safe battery dies or you forget your combination.

Comment: Note, I would like to upvote all answers. I just got the safe to prevent people in my household from tampering with my stuff, as silly as it may sound. So I got a relaxedsys-branded locker from amazon with 1-day delivery for 160$ and then an Abus-branded lockable key box for 48$. The latter has hardware-programmable 4-digit combination keys. My only regret was not finding a box with 8 or more such hardware digit wheels.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, safes without mechanical key override do exist. Talk to a real safe dealer, not your local big-box store. These will generally also be much stronger against physical attack. They will cost more, and weigh more, than the cheap toys ... and of course if you ever lose the combination you'll need an expert safe man's assistance to recover access to the contents.

Sentry and similar cheap combination-locked boxes *are not safes.* They're fire chests. If you're looking to protect paper or cds from a house fire, they're surprisingly effective for their price. (I'd recommend at least a 1-hour 350-degree rating.) But they are physically vulnerable in a number of ways, not just the key... and in fact may decrease security by attracting attention.

If you want both fire protection *and* security in the same box, expect to pay even more per cubic inch of storage. If you want to protect photographic or magnetic media from fire, likewise expect to pay more -- in that case, ask for a "media chest" and explain what materials you're protecting to get the best advice.

If you own the property, a floor safe may or may not give you some of these benefits at lower cost, though that adds installation cost.

Tl;dr: yes, if you're willing to pay for something decent rather that mass-market mismarketed consumer shlock.

Comment: For the record, Sentry makes actual safes too, in addition to lock boxes/fire chests.

Comment: Agreed about going to a safe dealer -- If your documents are so valuable that someone may physically steal the key from you to get into the lockbox, then you need a commercial quality safe that's rated for burglary resistance. Consumer safes without a UL Resistance Rating probably wouldn't stand up to 5 minutes of a thief attacking it with handtools (no matter how impressive the locking cylinders look).

Answer (score 3):

Safes need to have a physical, non electronic, way of opening them.

That key is used to open the safe when the fingerprint reader dies, or the batteries run out, or the other electronics malfunction.  The electronics can only be repaired from the inside of the door.

If you really want you could destroy the key, and fill the keyhole with epoxy.  Or just leave the key in the safe. But one day you will lose access to the safe, and either lose all your stuff or spend time/money destroying the safe to get inside.

Comment: No, actually, they don't. Downside is that without that bypass you need an expert to get into them without the combination. Upside is better security. See my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You are solving the wrong problem. 95% of house breakers go for unsecured jewelry and cash in the bedroom and do not do anything that would keep them in the house for longer than 5-10 minutes. The remaining 4.99% of robbers are "movers" that will back up a truck to your house and put everything in the truck that they find, including any safes. The remaining 0.01% are jewel thieves that will only rob your house if you are worth in excess of $10 million and you have jewels or art worth 6 to 7 figures. No safe of any kind stops those guys.

Comment: That varies with where you are and what you are trying to protect. Remember that this is an international discussion. While I'm a firm believer that for most folks it's sufficient to just be epsilon more secure than the neighbors,  there are exceptions and it's worth understanding the available options.

Answer (score -1):

um, seems pretty obvious to me.  Buy the one you like that has an over-ride key and then destroy the key?

Comment: Avoids theft of key; leaves you potentially vulnerable to picking or -- if badly designed -- force.